# How do I automate oracle DR with script run through putty

Tags: oracle, shell, terminal, automation

So I am Trying to sync my oracle production server to oracle dr server there is a set of command that I have to run each time to remove transport and apply lag. so fistly i have to login to putty
so to automate that I created an executable

putty.sh
which reads
`putty.exe -ssh servername  -l username(oracle) -pw password -m C:/auotomation/dgmgrl.sh(this is a file where my script is safe that I want to run)

the command in dgmgrl.sh file are

```
@echo off
dgmgrl
"and so on"
```

i am getting error that   bash: line 3: dgmgrl: command not found

I am not getting this error when typing this command manualy
I am getting errors while running dgmgrl;
I am also getting errors while running commands like sqlplus /nolog

but commands like LS and CD are running fine

Comment: Just configure your environment variables: path, ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID

Comment: can you elaborate I am fairly new to this It's a Linux red hat server?

Comment: ok got it but the new issue is that the next command after say sqlplus /nolog is not being registered.

Comment: ok got it but the new issue is that the next command after say sqlplus /nolog is not being registered.  ok they are being registered now but how do I stop shell file from closing "dgmgrl -echo << END". I am using $SHELL to stop it from closing now its not working

Comment: Just add `exit` command